# How to extract date, hours and minutes from datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas dataframe and I want extract date, hours and minutes to a new column in the following way. I also want to add integer variable at the end of the extracted date/hours/minte:

2017-10-25 10:11:12.002000+00:00

-> int_variable = 7

-> 201710251011 + int_variable

-> 2017102510117

What's the best way doing it?

Comment: *why* would you want to do such a thing? If this is about adding durations, have  look at [timedelta](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html)

Comment: I want to use the timestamp as an ID.
Due to the fact I have multiple machines maybe running at the same time, I need to add an int_variable at the end to distinguish.

Comment: hm seems error-prone to me, would keep the ID separately. No problem in a df. Can use groupby then, might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with join `int_variable` by convert to `str`:

```
df['date'].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M') + str(int_variable)
```